# Mobile phone menu: Display last 4 positions inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, list, inline

I am using bootstrap framework. I have the following code in my css file:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { 

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3d3d3d;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

Part of HTML file:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- SOCIAL ICONS -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="instagram"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        <li class="youtube"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li class="twitter"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></a></i></li>
        <li class="facebook"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></a></i></li>
      </ul>
      <!-- /SOCIAL ICONS -->


    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Thus, when the page is displayed on the mobile phone my menu would look like this:

[image]

Now, I want to display last 4 list items inline, with padding between them, so they are displayed evenly as squares in one line.

My question is, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by isolating the `.navbar`, then select the last `ul` (which contains the items in question), select the items `li` and float left with 25% width. You could also `display:inline-block`, however as they are on separate lines in your HTML you may end up with some 'erroneous' spacing.

```
.navbar ul:last-of-type li{
    float:left;
    width:25%; // or whatever dimensions you require, padding etc
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick solution! Works perfectly and perfectly explained! However I have  one more issue with this: is it possible to disable horizontal scroll that is visible now?

Comment: @media (max-width: 768px) { 
 .navbar-collapse {
           overflow-x: hidden;

 } fixes this

Answer (score 1):

Add a new class to the listelements, e.g. "social-icons"

```
.social-icons {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

Should work, if you use rests and border-box, else remove padding/margin or play with the width.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Add one class to social icons ul.

example- here i added "social_icons_list" class

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right social_icons_list">
    <li class="instagram"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    <li class="youtube"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    <li class="twitter"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></a></i></li>
    <li class="facebook"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></a></i></li>
  </ul>
```

Add below css to media query css.

```
       .social_icons_list li {float:left; width:25%;}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    ul.nav li {
        float:left; width:25%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a table instead of uunordered list . Like

```
<table >
  <tr>
    <td class="instagram"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></td>
    <td class="youtube"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></td>
    <td class="twitter"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></a></i></td>
    <td class="facebook"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></a></i></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can change the properties of the td using css to specify width and padding and margin to whatever you like and you can obtain what you have in mind.